# Paypal invalid merchant configuration error

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal sandbox environment to test payment for my site. Currently I am using PayPal pro (dodirectpayment) method. I create an account on PayPal send box using  PayPal pro option even then I got an invalid server configuration error.

The error I got is:

```
 10501 invalid merchant configuration.
```

I did not find  any solution until now.

Comment: I have done some R&D on that part and not able to find any solution. But i read something about paypal error in that case. Here is the link.                                                   https://www.x.com/content/update-1-issues-sandbox-preconfigured-accounts-jan-24                                                              If someone find any use full information.Please reply for that post.

Answer (score 3):

Just login to your developer.paypal.com account

1. Go to Applications -> Sandbox Accounts
2. Click any business type account you want to upgrade to Pro, and then
   click 'profile'
3. There should be an Upgrade to Pro option, click on it and enable the
   paypal pro payment.

[image]

It will change the account type to Business-Pro. Now you can get test API credentials and test.

It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This error typically means that you do not have the Website Payments Pro enabled on the account that you are trying to test with.  In some cases you can log into the particular account, and try to add it/sign up for it.  You could try creating another preconfigured account to see if it gets enabled on the new account.  Another option would be to contact PayPal MTS and see if they can enable this for you on your account as well.  Currently there are some issues with the sandbox that is preventing this from being set up correctly on some accounts.